# Remove Second Panel When Using Dash to Panel in 17.10

Tags: gnome-panel, 17.10

I have installed Dash to Panel in Ubuntu 17.10 as a GNOME extension. However, when I turn it on via the GNOME tweak tool extensions panel it appears but it is underneath my existing panel.  Because the existing panel is transparent I can see the new panel underneath and see that it is set up correctly. The top panel also disappears correctly.

What do I have to do to remove the pre-existing panel so that I am left with only the new 'Dash to Panel'?